# Get numbers separated by commas

Tags: c, c89

I got the following string:

`"312 ,22 ,+12 ,  -12  ,     5331"`

it is possible to have more than 1 space between numbers.

I need to convert it to an array like that:

`int arr[] = {312,22,-12,12,5331};`

Is there a pretty and elegant way to do this with C89?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`strtok`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strtok.html) + [`atoi`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/atoi.html):

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char numbers_str[] = "312 ,22 ,+12 ,-12 ,5331", *currnum;
    int numbers[5], i = 0;

    while ((currnum = strtok(i ? NULL : numbers_str, " ,")) != NULL)
        numbers[i++] = atoi(currnum);

    printf("%d\n", numbers[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: THANKS! this exactly what I meant when I said elegant!

Comment: This is nice, but it does leak memory since currnum will be NULL when the free(currnum) is done.

Comment: @VaughnCato Could you please elaborate? Edit: Ah, I understand! What should I do? Assign `"foobar"` to "currnum," before I call `free`? :P

Comment: Oh – that would not work, would it? I have to remove the whole `malloc` part, right?

Comment: Yeah, the malloc/free are completely unnecessary actually.

Comment: Thank you very much. I removed it now. : )

Answer (score 1):

Suggest:

1. Use `strtok()` to split the string into tokens.
2. Use `atoi()` to convert the tokens to `int`s.

For allocating the array to store the `int`s you could either:

1. Allocate as each token is processed, using `realloc()`, or
2. Have two passses through the string, with the first pass counting the tokens in the string and `malloc()` the array in a single operation.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int* make_int_array(char* a_str, size_t* const a_elem_count)
{
    int* result      = 0;
    char* tmp        = a_str;
    char* last_comma = 0;

    /* Count how many ints will be extracted. */
    *a_elem_count = 0;
    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (',' == *tmp)
        {
            (*a_elem_count)++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing int. */
    *a_elem_count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    result = malloc(sizeof(int) * (*a_elem_count));

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, ",");

        while (token)
        {
            assert(idx < *a_elem_count);
            *(result + idx++) = atoi(token);
            token = strtok(0, ",");
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "312 ,22 ,+12 ,-12 ,5331";
    int* int_list;
    size_t int_list_count = 0;

    printf("s=[%s]\n\n", s);

    int_list = make_int_array(s, &int_list_count);

    if (int_list)
    {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < int_list_count; i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", *(int_list + i));
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(int_list);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
s=[312 ,22 ,+12 ,-12 ,5331]

312
22
12
-12
5331
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `sscanf` function to get the integers into the array elements. I assume here there is a small fixed number of integers in your string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C programmer, but ANSI C (or C89) does have a "split" function called strtok.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

...

char string[] = "words separated by spaces -- and, punctuation!";
const char delimiters[] = " .,;:!-";
char *token;

...

token = strtok (string, delimiters);  /* token => "words" */
token = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => "separated" */
token = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => "by" */
token = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => "spaces" */
token = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => "and" */
token = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => "punctuation" */
token = strtok (NULL, delimiters);    /* token => NULL */
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `sscanf(str+offset, "%d,%n", &newValue, &offset)` repeatedly until it fails.

Comment: You are using C - so try/catch is not apart of that language! Look up the man page for `sscanf`. It returns an int to tell you if failure occured.

Comment: To handle failure, you would actually need `strtol` rather than `atoi`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any standard function to do this. This is such a common operation that most programmers have something like the following code in their personal toolkit.
The answer lies in using the strtol() function. I quickly hacked the following from the man page for strtol:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  char sep = ',';  
  char string[] = "  312 ,, 22 ,+12 ,-12 ,5331";
  /*
   * count separators
   */
  char *str = string;
  int j = 0;
  while (*str)
    {
      printf ("str=%c\n", *str);
      if (*str == sep)
    j++;
      str++;
    }
  int n = j + 1;
  printf ("n=%d\n", n);
  long int *arr = malloc (n * sizeof (long int));

  char *endptr = NULL;
  str = string;
  j = 0;
  do
    {
      arr[j++] = strtol (str, &endptr, 10);
      if (*endptr != '\0')
    {
      while (*endptr != sep)
        endptr++;
      str = endptr + 1;
    }
    }
  while (j < n && *endptr);
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      printf ("%d:%ld\n", j, arr[j]);
    }
  exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}                /* main */

Hope this is helpful

Comment: This code is thread-safe - other solutions using strtok should use strtok_r instead to make it thread-safe

Comment: The code posted by Gandaro is incorrect. It mallocs currnum before calling strtok. currnum is just a pointer into the array numbers_str. Also the array numbers_str will be modified by strtok by inserting nulls where the first separator is found. If the string is in the read-only data segment this code will fail. convention in these cases is to copy the string using strdup.